# extracting data from pdf

Tags: pdf, extract, pdf-parsing

how to extract data from pdf file mainly data table and such stuffs is there any free or open source tool available for doing it directly. I have to process a large number of files

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can extract text from pdf files to some extent using the lucene 3.x libraries and pdfbox 0.7

But from the pdf extraction you cant get the conversion some images and some formats will be converted into the binary and garabage code

But you can get the pure text

```
File f = new File("filename");

FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);

PDFParser parser=new PDFParser(fis);

parser.parse();

PDDocument pd=parser.getPDDocument();

PDFTextStripper pst=new PDFTextStripper();

String pdftext=pst.getText(pd);
```

For that you need to download the two  jar files 
1) lucene-core-3.0.3 jar
2) pdfbox-0.7.3 jar

I will help you in this don't worry

Answer (score 0):

For basic text extraction, if you have access to command line utilities, try [`pdftotext`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext) or [`pdftohtml`](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/). You could also use the `strings` command.